# how to use libreoffice --headless export more than one png image from ppt or pptx

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice

I use libreoffice export images, command like:
$ libreoffice --headless --convert-to png ./ /tmp/example.ppt

but this command only export one page, is first page image, how can export few image or specify page image?

Answer (score 0):

[unoconv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/doc2odt.1.html) accepts the parameter `-e PageRange=1-2` for the PDF output filter.  There may be a similar option for the png export filter, although it is not shown on the man page.

This should work instead:

1. Convert the .ppt file to .odp using `--convert-to`.
2. Unzip the .odp file.
3. Copy images from the `/Pictures` subfolder.